# Only first byte is received when sending string from client to server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, file-io

I made a client/server program and am sending a file from the client to the server.

Here is a piece of the code:

Client side:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt" ,"r");
size_t bytes = 0;
while(bytes = fread(buffer ,sizeof(char) , sizeof(buffer) ,f)>0)
{printf("buff%s\n" , buffer);
send(sockfd ,buffer ,bytes , 0);
} 
fclose(f);
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

Server side:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file1.txt" ,"w");
while(bytes = recv(newsockfd ,buffer , sizeof(buffer) ,0)>0)
{
printf("bytes%d" , bytes);
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char) ,bytes , f);
}
bytes = recv(newsockfd ,buffer , sizeof(buffer) ,0);
printf("bytessss%d" , bytes);
  fclose(f);  
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     close(newsockfd);
```

But when I send it to the server, the server makes a file and stores only the first byte, eg when I send "hi whats up ", the server only stores "h".

Answer (score 4):

You miss one parenthesis:

```
while(bytes = recv(newsockfd ,buffer , sizeof(buffer) ,0) > 0)
```

which make `bytes` variable 1 or 0, because the expression is calculated as  `recv(newsockfd ,buffer , sizeof(buffer) ,0) > 0` although the number of bytes read is the correct one. Add the parenthesis like that:

```
while ((bytes = recv(newsockfd ,buffer , sizeof(buffer) ,0)) > 0)
       ^                                                   ^
```

Missed that, but the same applies to your client, you read all the bytes to the buffer, but the `bytes` variable is again assigned with 1, since

```
while(bytes = fread(buffer ,sizeof(char) , sizeof(buffer) ,f)>0)
```

is evaluated this way:

```
while(bytes = (fread(buffer ,sizeof(char) , sizeof(buffer) ,f)>0) )
               ^
               1. call fread, keep the result in temporary place (let's call it X)
                                                              ^
                                                    2. compare "x" to 0
            ^
            3. store result of comparison (instead of fread) in the variable bytes.
```

meaning, read `sizeof(buffer)` bytes from the file, if the number of bytes read are bigger than 0, put 1 into `bytes`, else put 0 (the result of boolean expression is either 1 (true) or 0 (false)), so even if you read 100 bytes, the buffer is indeed filled with them, but the `bytes` variable is equal to **1** so you send **1 byte**. when you attempt to read again, there's nothing to read, since last time **you already read 100 bytes**. The extra parenthesis makes it first to assign the number of bytes read to `bytes` variable and only then compare it to 0:

```
while((bytes = fread(buffer ,sizeof(char) , sizeof(buffer) ,f))>0)
```

Comment: yes it worked thanks sir please can you explain me what happende like how it making 1 tp 0 thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer explains, precedence rule is the one and only  problem in your code.

**> has higher precedence than =.**

I think first 2 answers for the below given question will help you....

[C write() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281934/problem-with-write-function)

I think that guy had a  same problem as like you....